# How to disable past date 5 days back in ajax control toolkit calendar extender

Tags: c#, asp.net

//  This is my Code Behind

```
TextBox dt = (TextBox)f.Controls[0].FindControl("TextBox1");
                dt.Text = string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
                CalendarExtender c1 = (CalendarExtender)f.Controls[0].FindControl("CalenderExtender1");

This code decide disable date

                c1.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);  //to dissable past Date but i want 5 days back ??????????
                c1.EndDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);//to dissable future  Date
```

anyone Can help me ?

Comment: "to dissable past Date but i want 5 days back ? " do you mean you can only pick 5 days back from current day?

Comment: yes that is i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your existing code I think on this line

```
 c1.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 1, 1);
```

try to changed it similiar into your endDate but add -5

```
 c1.StartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,DateTime.Today.Month,DateTime.Today.Day -5);
```

not 100% sure cause im not tested it yet

Comment: Great sir, it's work but i must a little edit -5 to be -4 . in the next question a relate my question but specific user can see that.